# Decoding Url Parameter Values in ASP.NET MVC App

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an app built with ASP.NET MVC. My views are using Razor. One of my views is navigated to using a url like the following:

```
http://localhost:5001/find?s=You%27re
```

I need to get the human-friendly version of the query string parameter `s`. To do that, I currently have the following in the bottom of my ASP.NET MVC view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var s = '@HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["s"])';
  alert(s);
</script>
```

When this code gets executed, I can view the code in the browser and I see the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var s = 'You&#39;re';
  alert(s);
</script>
```

I was expecting to see:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var s = "You're";
  alert(s);
</script>
```

How do I do this in ASP.NET MVC? I know the problem has something to do with the quotes. Yet, I'm not sure how to overcome it.

Thank you!

Comment: Why can't you pass this value from the controller?

Comment: man, you must to read about mvc routing

Comment: you do realise `&#39;` is the html encoding for '? Is the issue because you're trying to read it using JavaScript? Have you tried not calling `UrlDecode`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Razor views encode server-side strings by default. To turn off Html encoding, the framework provides the Html.Raw helper.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

```
var s = "@Html.Raw(Request.QueryString["s"])";
```

or wrap with single quote and escape single quote characters:

```
var s = '@Html.Raw((Request.QueryString["s"] ?? String.Empty).Replace("'","\\'"))';
```

Be aware that this code is vulnerable to script injection.

Comment: Could you add some explanation to this? Posting a line of of code won't be helpful to somebody who doesn't understand **how** it works.